# No getter method for property value of bean error with nested logic iterate tags

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, struts

I am trying to iterate an ArrayList "sampleBeanList" in my jsp using logic:iterate. Each SampleBean object contains a variable ArrayList "subBeanList" in it. I am using another logic:iterate tag inside the first tag to iterate such that once the form is submitted, I can retrieve the data in the form of ArrayList "sampleBeanList" and also ArrayList "subBeanList" variable for each SampleBean. I added setters and getters accordingly as shown below. But, I am not able to understand the problem because when I am running, I am getting the below error:

"No getter method for property value of bean subBeanElement"

Source Code:

JSP:

```
<logic:iterate id="toFamilyElement" name="myRolloverForm" property="sampleBeanList" indexId="toFamilyIndex"  type="MYRolloverFamilyBean">
    <tr>    
        <td align="center">
            <%=sno%>    
        </td>
        <td align="center" rowspan="<bean:write name="toFamilyElement" property="toFamilyListSize"/>">
            <bean:write name="toFamilyElement" property="fromFamily"/>
        </td>   
        <td align="center" rowspan="<bean:write name="toFamilyElement" property="toFamilyListSize"/>">
            <IMG src="images/rightArrow.png" width="35px" height="30px" />
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <table width="100%" height="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <%int toFamilyListCount = 0; %>
                <logic:iterate id="subBeanElement" name="toFamilyElement" property="toFamilyList" indexId="toFamilyListIndex" type="String">
                    <html:hidden styleId='<%="toFamilyCode[" + toFamilyCount+"]["+toFamilyListCount+"]"%>' indexed="true" name="subBeanElement" property="value"/>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <bean:write name="subBeanElement" property="value"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <%toFamilyListCount++; %>
                </logic:iterate>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <%toFamilyCount++; 
    sno++;%>    
</logic:iterate>
```

MYRolloverForm (form bean which contains SampleBeanList variable):

```
public class MYRolloverForm extends ActionForm {


    private ArrayList<SampleBean> sampleBeanList= new ArrayList<SampleBean>();

    public ArrayList<SampleBean> getSampleBeanList() {
        return sampleBeanList;
    }

    public void setSampleBean(ArrayList<SampleBean> sampleBeanList) {
        this.sampleBeanList = sampleBeanList;
    }

    public void setToFamilyElement(int index, SampleBean value) {
        this.sampleBeanList.add(value);
    }

    public SampleBean getToFamilyElement(int index) {
        int size = sampleBeanList.size();
        while (index >= size) {
            sampleBeanList.add(new SampleBean());
            size = sampleBeanList.size();
        }
        return this.sampleBeanList.get(index);
    }
}
```

SampleBean (contains subBeanList):

```
public class SampleBean implements Serializable {

    private ArrayList<String> subBeanList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ArrayList<String> getSubBeanList() {
        return subBeanList;
    }

    public void setSubBeanList(ArrayList<String> subBeanList) {
        this.subBeanList = subBeanList;
    }

    public void setSubBeanElement(int index, String value) {
        this.subBeanList.add(value);
    }

    public String getSubBeanElement(int index) {
        int size = subBeanList.size();
        while (index >= size) {
            subBeanList.add(new String());
            size = subBeanList.size();
        }
        return this.subBeanList.get(index);
    }
}
```

Please suggest a solution!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem. I am trying to get the property "value" of a String element in the second logic:iterate loop. This is why I am getting the above error. I modified such that instead of ArrayList, I am using ArrayList where OptionBean is a class defined with "value" variable in it. It resolved my problem. Thanks for the Answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are messing the elements of the list with the properties of each element:

`name` should be the bean (a SampleBean) and `value` the name of the property you want to access (subBeanElement):

```
<logic:iterate id="mySample" name="toFamilyElement" property="toFamilyList" indexId="toFamilyListIndex" type="String">
    <html:hidden styleId='<%="toFamilyCode[" + toFamilyCount+"]["+toFamilyListCount+"]"%>' indexed="true" name="mySample" property="subBeanElement"/>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <bean:write name="mySample" property="subBeanElement"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <%toFamilyListCount++; %>
</logic:iterate>
```